# How do I represent a collection of disjoint set in terms of a collection of not disjoint sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a finite sequence of (not necessarily disjoint) sets $A_1, A_2,  \cdots , A_n$. I have another finite sequence of sets $E_1, E_2, \cdots , E_n$ such that $E1, E2, \cdots, En$ are disjoint, and, for all $k : 1 ≤ k ≤ n$.

So essentially: $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup\cdots \cup A_k = E_1 \cup E_2 \cup\cdots\cup E_k$

So I can say:

$$\sum_i |A_i|- \sum_{i < j} |A_i \cap A_j|+ \sum_{i < j < k} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k|+ (-1)^{n-1} |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap\cdots \cap  An|   \\=   |E_1| + |E_2| + |E_3| +\cdots+ |E_n|$$

Now my question is how can I represent $E_i$ in terms of $A_1 A_2 \cdots$? Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: Whether or not you are heading in the wrong direction depends on pieces of information that you haven't written (namely *what* you are trying to accomplish). That being said, no sensible way to write the $E_i$-s in terms of the $A_i$-s comes to mind, and possibly there isn't. For instance, you can write $[0,1]=[0,\frac12)\cup [\frac12,\frac23)\cup [\frac23,1]=[0,\frac15)\cup [\frac14,\frac79]\cup (\frac{14}{27},1]$

Comment: So you want expressions for e.g. $|E_1|$ in the $|A_i|$? If so then impossible. Take for instance $n=2$ and $A_1=A_2=E_1\cup E_2$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yes, that's what I thought, as you can never represent Ei in terms of Ai. So I basically used inverse function to find that, though that is not a good solution.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee What do you mean by inverse function here? I think mean by $|E_1|+|E_2|+\cdots +|E_n|$ in the right side of the equality.